# Correct way to define variables and methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a `Person` class in Ruby which has some methods and properties. The below is how I have implemented it now.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :gender, :mother, :spouse

  def initialize(name, gender, mother = nil)
    @name = name
    @gender = gender
    @mother = mother
    @spouse = nil
  end

  def add_spouse(spouse)
    if spouse
      @spouse = spouse
      spouse.spouse = self
    end
  end
  
  def father(self)
    return [self.mother.spouse]
  end
end
```

I want to access the methods like this:

```
m = Person.new('mom', 'Female')
d = Person.new('dad', 'Male')

d.add_spouse(m)

p = Person.new('Jack', 'Male', m)
```

If I want to get the `father` of `p`, then I want to get it like this: `p.father`.

So is the above implementation correct?

In python if I want a class method as a property then `@property` is used. In Ruby is there anything like that or is the above method for `father` property correct?
Also I have seen examples with `self.some_variable` and `@some_variable` in Ruby. Here `name` and `gender` variables are defined at the object creation and never changed but other variables like `mother`, `children` can be `nil` initially and can be added by some other external method. For eg: By a method `add_member` in `class Family`. So for that is the above definition correct?

Comment: This question if off-topic on [codereview.se], as per the [help]. [codereview.se] is for review of *working code*, so the question "is this code correct" is off-topic. Besides that, the code has a trivial `SyntaxError`, it isn't even legal Ruby. You might get better help on [so], but please make sure to produce a *minimal reproducible example*. In particular, the `SyntaxError` can be trivially reproduced in one line, it doesn't require 22 lines of code to show.

Comment: "So is the above implementation correct?" Did you test it? Please see our [help/on-topic].

Comment: I had put `self` in `def father` initially. Then I changed it in my code but while typing the question I mistyped it. I have changed it now.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Next time, make sure your first revision is the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has an error in the definition of father.
In ruby, there is no need to add self as a parameter.
In addition you return an array with the mother. This may be correct under some legal systems, but I think you didn't want to implement this..

It is fine, if you use:

```
def father()
  return self.mother.spouse
end
```

Then you can use it as `son.father`.

---

Ruby defines instance variables as `@varname`, you can use them inside the class.

If you want to have access from outside, you must define accessors (setter, getter or both). From outside you don't see a difference between accessors and "normal" methods. You call a method and get a result.

Inside a class I recommend to use the accessor if it is defined. If you ever replace the standard accessor with a programm logic, then you don't need to adapt the code.

Comment: Most coding styles would just write `def father`, without the parentheses, instead of `def father()` and just `mother.spouse`  instead of `return self.mother.spouse`, neither the return nor the self are necessary here